# Python3 Not Recognizing pytube or pytube3 module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pytube

I know this question may have been asked, I did some research, searched through numerous forums and still cannot find a solution. I installed pytube and pytube 3 using each of these commands (I use VS Code Studio as my IDE)

```
pip install pytube
pip install pytube3
pip3 install pytube
pip3 install pytube3
```

tried numerous versions of these and they all successfully download pytube however when i use the import code

```
import pytube
```

it always gives me and error message and says "ImportError: No module named pytube" even though i successfully downloaded it using pip and or pip3

How do I get python/ and or VS Code IDE to recognize pytube? This does not happen with any other module I have/ have installed in the past. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, to anyone else struggling with this make sure the environment you're in is the correct one, for some reason VS Code had me in python 2.7 when i switched it started working.

WHen you run it you might get a long list of errors with the cause being somethithing with the SSL Certificate just use this short code at the beginning of your program and everything should work

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and what i did was that i made an venv folder in my project folder using this command in the VS Code terminal. **python -m venv "the folder path"** after that you can uninstall pytube and install it using a new terminal in VS Code (Terminal -> New Terminal) then install pytube using **pip install pytube** and it should work.